# Firebase frameworks hosting not working as expected

Tags: firebase, express, firebase-hosting

I have a project where I've followed [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/express) to set up hosting for an app using Express.

My firebase.json looks like this:

```json
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "source": "web",
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "europe-west1"
    }
  }
}
```

My web app is in the `web` directory, and in there, the `package.json` file looks like this:

```json
"name": "web",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=creds/credentials.json node devserver",
    "build:client": "vite build --ssrManifest --outDir dist/client",
    "build:server": "vite build --ssr src/entry-server.tsx --outDir dist/server",
    "build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "directories": {
    "serve": "dist/client/assets"
  },
  "files": [
    "index.html",
    "dist",
    "server.js"
  ],
  "main": "server.js",
  // ...deps
}
```

When I do `firebase deploy`, I see that the build script runs, and it correctly uploads the files from "dist/client/assets", (I can access them directly through the hosting URL), but it does not seem to deploy the actual express app. When I visit the index page of my hosting domain, it gives me a "Page not found" error. I was expecting the index to be rendered by the express app.
I don't see anything in the command's output that might indicate what the issue is.

Comment: "*but it does not seem to deploy the actual express app*" - please edit your question to explain what you are doing or observing this shows this to be the case.  Please include any relevant code and error messages that illustrate the issue.  We should be able to reproduce the issue using the code and instructions you provide.

Comment: I've updated the question to indicate that I've tried accessing my deployed app, and am getting a "Page not found" error, while I'd expect that route to be served by my app.

Comment: is it for an api ? Can you show your express configuration? I think your issue is related to rewrites in firebase.json . You should try to specify source and function that you have exported

Comment: No, it's for a server rendered app, so anything that's not a static file should be routed to the NodeJS backend

Comment: Please edit the question to show a complete minimal reproducible example.  What *exactly* are you deploying, and what can we do to see the same behavior?